# Ring of integers of arithmetically disjoint fields

Tags: number-theory

This is a follow up of https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335506/quotients-of-a-ring-of-integers.

Let $K_1,K_2$ be two number fields which are linearly disjoints, with coprime discrimiants. Assume that $\mathcal{O}_{K_i}=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha_i], i=1,2$.

Let $L=K_1K_2.$ Do we have $\mathcal{O}_L=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ for some $\alpha\in\mathcal{O}_L$ ? (for example, does $\alpha=\alpha_1+\alpha_2$ works ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call a number field $K$ **monogenic** if  there is some $\alpha\in\mathcal O_K$ such that $\mathcal O_K= \mathbb Z[\alpha]$. It's clear that every quadratic field is monogenic. In order to answer your question in the negative I'll exhibit a biquadratic number field which is not monogenic.

Proposition 2 of [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0ba0/a35b7976153f610803e19bee074b90ef37fe.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwisvbfD3p7jAhXrRd8KHaz5CBIQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw3NclLsiBl7MoUDJP6lL_cp) paper shows that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{x}, \sqrt{y})$ is not monogenic when $$x\equiv y \equiv 1\pmod{3}.$$

This shows that while $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{13})$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{37})$
are monogenic, their compositum $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{13}, \sqrt{37})$ is not.

Comment: It seems the argument is $x,y \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ implies $(3,\sqrt{x}-1,\sqrt{y}-1),(3,\sqrt{x}+1,\sqrt{y}-1),(3,\sqrt{x}-1,\sqrt{y}+1),(3,\sqrt{x}+1,\sqrt{y}+1)$ are 4 distinct maximal ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{x},\sqrt{y}]$, if $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{x},\sqrt{y}] \subset \Bbb{Z}[\alpha] = \Bbb{Z}[t]/(f(t))$ then $f$ must have $4$ distinct roots in $\Bbb{F}_3$ a contradiction